# How to use final keyword in java

Tags: android, android-activity

I have developed a small android app. I have used final keyword and initialized the resource imageView in the create method. I have defined a private method in which I have used imageview but it gives me red marks on the left side. Please, could anyone help me how to write. this program. Thanks for the help in advance.

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnPrevious= null;
    Button btnNext = null;
    TextView txtTest = null;

    int conditions[];
    String days[];

    // condition imageView initialization together with declaration 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        //ImageView Initialization


        btnPrevious =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious2);
        btnNext =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext2);
        txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest2);

        final ImageView T1C4R4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C4R4);
        final ImageView T2C4R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C4R5);
        final ImageView T4C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C4R1);
        final ImageView T3C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C4R1);

        // imageView initialization together with declaration

        final ImageView T1C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C4R1); 
        final ImageView T1C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C2R3);
        final ImageView T1C1R4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C1R4);

        final ImageView T2C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C4R1);
        final ImageView T2C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C2R3);
        final ImageView T2C1R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C1R5);

        final ImageView T4C1R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C1R1);
        final ImageView T4C2R2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C2R2);
        final ImageView T4C5R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C5R5);

        final ImageView T3C4R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C4R5);
        final ImageView T3C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C2R3);
        final ImageView T3C1R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C1R1);

        final ImageView[][] dressImageView =
            {
                {T1C4R1, T1C2R3, T1C1R4},
                {T2C4R1,T2C2R3, T2C1R5} ,
                {T4C1R1, T4C2R2,T4C5R5},
                {T3C4R5, T3C2R3, T3C1R1}
            }; 

        final ImageView [] dayCell = {T1C4R4 ,T2C4R5, T4C4R1, T3C4R1 };


        // get the Intent that started this Activity
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // get the Bundle that stores the data of this Activity
        Bundle b = in.getExtras();

        // getting data from bundle
        conditions = b.getIntArray("condition");
        days = b.getStringArray("day");

        // show data to layout
        txtTest.setText("[Condition: " + conditions[0] + ", " + conditions[1] + ", " + conditions[2] + ", " + conditions[3] + "]");

        for (int c = 0; c < conditions.length; c++) {
            //dayWeatherCondtion(dc, days[dc]);                  
            weatherCondition(c, conditions[c]);         
        }
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putInt("condition", conditions[1]);
                b.putString("day", days[1]);

                // Creating Intent object
                Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                // Storing bundle object into intent
                in.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    private void weatherCondition(int day, int condition) {   

        switch(condition){
        case 10: 
        {
            //String dress_array[] = ;
            weatherDress(day, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five));      
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        case 6:
        {
            //  String dress_array[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five);
            weatherDress(day, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five));
            break;
        }
    }
    }

private void weatherDress(int day, String[] dress_array) {
        for(int d = 0; d  < dress_array.length; d++ ){
            //ImageView temp = dressImageView[d];

        dressImageView[day][d].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, dress_array[d]));

        }
    }

    public Drawable getDrawableByName(Context context, String name){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
                context.getPackageName());
        return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
    }

}
```

Comment: What error it is showing ? when you hover your cursor there ?

Comment: red symbol comes left side. Tried to run then I shows project has error

Comment: `public class SecondActivity extends Activity {`

    **final ImageView T1C4R4;** <<<<== delete this line from code

Comment: Can You tell me where you getting error?

Comment: I have not written in my code below the class.

Comment: I am getting error in the below given code

Comment: private void weatherDress(int day, String[] dress_array) {
  for(int d = 0; d  < dress_array.length; d++ ){
   //ImageView temp = dressImageView[d];
  
  dressImageView[day][d].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, dress_array[d]));
   
  }

Comment: Hover the cursor over there and tell me the error what it says?

Comment: Yes because 

final ImageView[][] dressImageView =
            {
                {T1C4R1, T1C2R3, T1C1R4},
                {T2C4R1,T2C2R3, T2C1R5} ,
                {T4C1R1, T4C2R2,T4C5R5},
                {T3C4R5, T3C2R3, T3C1R1}
            }; 

this you have defined locally in the onCreate Method 

so you wont get the refrence for the object dressImageView in the other method

is this helpful @J.Vyas

Comment: Please, could you change in it and show me. thanks for the reply

Comment: J. Vyas Please check my answer let me know if it is help ful or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your private method is trying to access the first `final ImageView T1C4R4;` which is **null**.

And the moment you create a **final variable**, you have to initialize it since you won't be able to reassign it again with a different value.

Comment: Can you guide me how to solve the problem. Thanks for the reply

Comment: delete `final ImageView T1C4R4;` which you have written before `oncreate()` method

Comment: I have not written below the class

Comment: i think he removed that line from question

Comment: @ J. Vyas, C'mon why change your code after answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

Vyas

I dont know what you are trying to achive with this code but yes i can give you a solution for your problem

You need to pass the refrence of the dressImageView object recursively where you use that object

for e.g.

```
weatherCondition(c, conditions[c], dressImageView);
.....
case 10:
    {
        //String dress_array[] = ;
        weatherDress(day, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five),dressImageView);
        break;
    }
....
```

Comment: private void weatherDress(int day, String[] dress_array, ImageView dressImageView) {
  for(int d = 0; d  < dress_array.length; d++ ){
   //ImageView temp = dressImageView[d];
  
  dressImageView[day][d].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, dress_array[d]));
dressImageView[day][d]. it say  dressImage must be array.

Comment: Yes define like this weatherDress(int day, String[] dress_array,ImageView[][] dressImageView)

Comment: getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nine) particular array sitting in the string folder     <string-array name="nine">
        <item name="dress_6">dress_6</item>
        <item name="dress_4">dress_4</item>
        <item name="dress_14">dress_14</item>
    </string-array>
dress_6.png, dress_4.png, and dress_14.png is a file in drawable folder. I want to display this all images using following two functions

Comment: private void weatherDress(int day, String[] dress_array, ImageView[][] dressImageView) {
  for(int d = 0; d  < dress_array.length; d++ ){
   //ImageView temp = dressImageView[d];
  
  dressImageView[day][d].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, dress_array[d]));
   
  }
 }
 //

Comment: public Drawable getDrawableByName(Context context, String name){
  Resources resources = context.getResources();
  final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
    context.getPackageName());
  return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
 } . But It does not display these images. Please, I don't know how to achieve using these above two function. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your method getDrawableByName is correct no issues on that just debug and check did you get the array and the name of the image that you want on method weatherDress

if you still have issues just give me your code i will update and give you back

Comment: hey whats the reason you have accepted the Colns Abt answer ?